# javascript vk api

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть код:

```
function ferd() {
   var terin;
   VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: 210700286, fields: 'bdate'}, function(r) {
        if(r.response) {
           terin = r.response[0].bdate;
           alert(r.response[0].bdate);
        }
   }); 

   console.log(terin);
}
```

Появляется ошибка

> TypeError: `'terin' of undefined`

Как присвоить terin значение из VK.API

Так же при работе с массивом.

```
var terin = [];
function ferd() {
VK.Api.call('friends.get', {
 user_ids: id_vk, fields: 'uid,first_name'
}, function(data) {

    if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error.error_msg);
    } else {

        if (data.response.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.response.length; i++) {

               terin.push(data.response[i].user_id);

            }
        }
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

переменная `terin` будет присвоена только в callback функции.

Один из вариантов использовать [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) для работы с асинхронными данными.

```
function ferd() {
    var terin = [],
        terinPr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: 210700286, fields: 'bdate'}, function(r) {
              if(r.response) {
              terin = r.response[0].bdat;
              alert(r.response[0].bdate);
              resolve(r);
          }
      }); 

    });

    terinPr.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    })

}
```

**Обновлено**. Тестовый код с обещаниями:

```
function ferd() {
var terin = [],
    terinPr = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: 210700286, fields: 'bdate'}, function(r) {
        if (data.error) {
            reject(data.error.error_msg);
        } else {
            resolve(data.response);
        }
  }); 

});

terinPr.then(function (response) {
   if (response.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                terin.push(response[i].user_id);
            }
        }
});

}
```

**Обновлено 23.02.17**. вариант а калбэк функциями JQUERY:

```
    var terin = [];
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add( setTerin );

function setTerin (response){
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        terin.push(response[i].user_id);
    }
    console.log(terin);
}

function ferd() {
        VK.Api.call('users.get', {user_ids: 210700286, fields: 'bdate'}, function(r) {
              if(r.response) {
              callbacks.fire( r.response );
           }
       }); 

}
```

Comment: Можно пример как присвоить?

Comment: Обновил пример. Там у вас r.response[0].bdat, а алерт r.response[0].bdate я посмотрите какой правильный

Comment: А как быть с массивом? Добавил в шапку

Comment: Обновил тестовый пример.

Comment: Мне массив terin  нужно будет использовать в другом месте, это возможно?

Comment: Массив можно будет использовать только тогда, когда выполнится калбек в  VK.Api.call. Вам придется либо проверять на пустоту terin, что не очень хорошо. Второй вариант  создать своё событие и потом подписаться на него. Ну а третий вариант -  построить работу в калбек функции промиса terinPr.then.

Comment: Если будет интересно как c callback функциями работать могу тоже подсказать

Comment: Обращаюсь к terin после VK.api, он пустой - Это меня не устраивает. Если в c# в асинхронном методе обратится к массиву/списку то он будет заполнен корректно

Comment: А response нормальный приходит? И где вы смотрели внутри калбек функции ?

Comment: Добавил вариант с jQuery.Callbacks()

Comment: jQuery.Callbacks() можно использовать только один? Так с двумя у меня уже не работает

Comment: Не совсем понял что не работает. 
var callbacks1 = $.Callbacks();
callbacks1.add( setTerin );
var callbacks2 = $.Callbacks();
callbacks2.add( setTerin2 );

Comment: и соответственно callbacks1.fire('data1') callbacks2.fire('data2')

Comment: Работает только там
callbacks.remove(setTerin);
callbacks.add(setTerin1);
Если создать callbacks1 то не работает

Comment: а, точно, надо очищать события